# How to unbrick my device (yuphoria)

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I was using CM 13 nightlies for the past few months, everything was working fine without any issue but day before yesterday all of a sudden my devices rebooted and showed something like device encrypted or something like that. Being unable to use my device I thought i should change my ROM to a stable one so i went into twrp and tried installing new ROM but to my surprise the internal storage was showing 0Mb.

I searched internet about this issue and did something like formatting data or wiping everything except the storage. Nothing seems to work and i keep getting this error which says

- "unable to mount /data (invalid argument)"
- "unable to mount /cache ( invalid argument)"

here are the screenshots:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

I even tried flashing the stock ROM through fastboot but that also seems to be not working. It is failing to write system partition and desplaying this message
FAILED (remote: flash write failure)
Here is the screen shot

[image]

Than i tried adb sideload. This also gave me no luck. Here is the screenshot of the process.

[image: screenshot]

Now I feel hopeless :(
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also have same problem, Did you able to find any solution to this ??

Comment: It seems the partition is corrupted. Try formatting the partitions manually from TWRP's terminal using `mkfs`. If it doesn't help, try `fsck`. If still that doesn't work, I'm afraid this is the only way: **[Fixing a hardbricked Yuphoria (lettuce) using an external SD card](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/unofficial-fixing-a-hardbricked-yuphoria-lettuce-using-an-external-sd-card.35923/)**..